# Cannot use Debug on Zend

Tags: php, debugging, zend-debugger

Greetings,
I done the debugger setup on a WAMP server...

What happens is that it says that a timeout error ocurred when the debug server attempted to connect the following IP/Host 127.0.0.1

I already added to the php.ini
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always

this is running on my machine... I don't know how to fix this... can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Check following,

1. The ZendDebugger is installd as zend_extension, not a regular extension.
2. The dummy.php is in your document root.

Read this document for details,

http://static.zend.com/topics/Zend-Debugger-Installation-Guide.pdf